# Use jQuery to get element after HTML comment

Tags: jquery, comments

I need to select an element based on a preceeding HTML comment. This is in SharePoint 2013 and unfortunately I find that when I move content from POC to test to prod SP can change DOM attributes like Title. The one thing that remains consistent is the system generated comments that precede the element I need to select. The html looks like:

```
<td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
    <!-- FieldName="Location Name"
         FieldInternalName="ENV_LocationLookup"
         FieldType="SPFieldLookup"
      -->
        <span dir="none">
            <select title="Location Name Required Field" id="ENV_LocationLookup_ebd540c2-1e76-440a-931b-b513ad653d80_$LookupField">
                <option value="1">Location 1</option>
                <option value="2">Location 2</option>
            </select>
        </span>
</td>
```

I need a function that I can send the value of FieldInternalName (in this case"ENV_LocationLookup") and return the value of the next "select" element (in this case the one where title="Location Name Required Field").

I need to do it this way because the title can change, but the FieldInternalName in the preceeding comment remains constant.

I have found this handy bit of code that returns the comments, but I don't know how to search within that and then find the next "select" element.

```
$("*").contents().filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType == 8;
        }).each(function(i, e){
            alert(e.nodeValue);
        });
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This way you get the `id` of the `select` element you want as long as it is the next one after the comments.

```js
$("*").contents().filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType == 8;
        }).each(function(i, v){
            alert($(v).next().find("select").prop('id'));
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
    <!-- FieldName="Location Name"
         FieldInternalName="ENV_LocationLookup"
         FieldType="SPFieldLookup"
      -->
        <span dir="none">
            <select title="Location Name Required Field" id="ENV_LocationLookup_ebd540c2-1e76-440a-931b-b513ad653d80_$LookupField">
                <option value="1">Location 1</option>
                <option value="2">Location 2</option>
            </select>
        </span>
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Thank you, Peter. That looks like it might work. I'll plug it in tomorrow morning and see how it goes.

Comment: OK. That did what it was supposed to do, but wasn't exactly what I need. I should have clarified that there are many more elements on the page with comments. I need to select the "select" element immediately after the comment that contains < FieldInternalName="ENV_LocationLookup" >

Comment: Also, what are i and v in this instance?

Comment: @m.t.Dutch The index of the `.each()` loop is `i`, `v` is the value of the array of elements at that certain index every time. Can you post some more code to update the example.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter. Using the code you provided I was able to build the function I needed.

Answer (score 0):

So, building on what Peter provided, I wound up with this. There may be more elegant ways, but this one does work.

```
var comment;
comment = 'FieldInternalName="ENV_LocationLookup"';
var locNameElm = findElementAfterComment(comment, "select");
alert(locNameElm.val());

function findElementAfterComment(text, type) {
    var nextOfType;
    $("*").contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType == 8;
    }).each(function (i, v) {
        if (v.text.match(text)) {
            nextOfType = $(v).next().find(type);
            return;
        }
    });
    return nextOfType;
}
```